# Read From Excel To GridView In ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to read data from Excel file `xlsx` and bind the data to GridView. But when I try in this way I get the following exception

**The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.**

Any idea how to fix it ?

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xlsx"].ConnectionString;
            // Create the connection object
            OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                // Open connection
                oledbConn.Open();

                // Create OleDbCommand object and select data from worksheet Sheet1
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);

                // Create new OleDbDataAdapter
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                // Create a DataSet which will hold the data extracted from the worksheet.
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                // Fill the DataSet from the data extracted from the worksheet.
                oleda.Fill(ds, "Employees");

                // Bind the data to the GridView
                this.gvExcel.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                this.gvExcel.DataBind();
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close connection
                oledbConn.Close();
            } 
        }
    }
```

aspx code:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvExcel" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```